# Divide from table each row with the sum of the same table

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have got a query that shows Events and for this events there are durations. 
To get the Duration I did a calculation in my query:

```
Sum(cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)) as Duration,
```

The Table:

```
Event   Duration
[Pr     10,48
[Al     9,89
[To     1,32
[Co     0,41
[Gh     0,33
```

And I must divide each of this row with the sum of the column Duration. For Example: The Sum of the column Duration is =22,43. 
--> (10,48/22,43)*100 = 46,72%

I tried this here:

```
Sum(cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)) / (SELECT Sum(cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)) From Event) as SumOfDuration
```

But this gave me not the correct result.
I use SSRS

Comment: Version of DB? Is it Sql Server?

Comment: I use sql server management studio

Comment: but what version of database? Is right by the DB Name on SSMS (10.5, 11.0 etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL approach:

```
select event, duration, duration/sum(duration) over (partition by 1) percent
 from (
       select event, sum(cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)) as Duration
       from t
       group by event) as t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in SSRS.

Let's say you have a column with Duration, and a details row group with Event.
With an expression like:

```
SUM(Fields!Duration.Value) / SUM(Fields!Duration.Value,"Events")
```

Replace "Events" with the name of your detail group

[SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283120.aspx) has a SCOPE optional parameter